# There are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap V = \emptyset $ and $ U \cap \tau(V) =\emptyset $?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, self-learning

I am in a series of self-studies in the book [Vector Analysis](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Vector_Analysis.html?id=agIc62fKOfoC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y) written by Klaus Janich. By page 15 of the book is made the affirmation (without explicit proof) that we can choose (under the considerations below) open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap V =\emptyset $ and $ U \cap \tau(V) =\emptyset $.

In this page, $\tau:M\to M$ is a fixed-point-free involution (*i.e.*
a differentiable map with $\tau\circ\tau=\mathrm{id}_M$ and $\tau(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in M$) and $M$ a $m$-dimensional manifold.

> **QUESTION.** Under these considerations how can we prove that there are open sets $U\neq \emptyset$ and $V\neq \emptyset$ such that $U\cap V = \emptyset $ and $ U \cap \tau(V) =\emptyset $?

In my attempts, the only things I have been able to prove are that
$$
U\cap V=\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow \tau(U)\cap \tau(V)=\emptyset
\qquad \mathrm{ and } \qquad 
U\cap \tau(V)=\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow \tau(U)\cap V=\emptyset
$$

Comment: Perhaps $U = V = \varnothing$ should be ruled out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lee Mosher's answer doesn't quite appear to answer the question asked by the OP, since he finds $U,V$ such that $U\cap V=\varnothing$ but $U\cap \tau(V)\ne \varnothing$ instead of $U\cap \tau(V)=\varnothing$, but a modification of his technique should work.

Pick an arbitrary $x\in M$, and choose $y\ne x,\tau(x)$. Let $V_1,U_1$ be neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ such that $V_1\cap U_1 =\varnothing$ and let $V_2,U_2$ be neighborhoods of $\tau(x)$ and $y$ such that $V_2\cap U_2=\varnothing$ by Hausdorffness of $M$. Then let 
$$U=U_1\cap U_2 \quad\textrm{and}\quad V=V_1\cap \tau(V_2).$$ $U$ and $V$ are both nonempty, since $U$ contains $y$ and $V$ contains $x$. Then
$$U\cap V \subseteq U_1\cap V_1 =\varnothing\quad \textrm{and}\quad U\cap \tau(V)\subseteq U_2\cap \tau(\tau(V_2))=U_2\cap V_2=\varnothing.$$

Comment: Oops, darnit, how did I misread that?

Answer (score 2):

Pick any $x \in M$. Let $y = \tau(x)$, so we know that $x \ne y$. Since every manifold is a [Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space), there exist open sets $U,V \subset M$ such that $x \in U$, and $y \in V$, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Since $\tau(y)=\tau(\tau(x))=x \in U$, it follows that $x \in U \cap \tau(V)$ and so $U \cap \tau(V) \ne \emptyset$.